# HTTP response code for a "best try"

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

I have a service (façade) which takes a "token", it then decodes it to retrieve some information (an id) and then calls another external service to get some additional information.

```
{"id":"foo","other-stuff":"bar"}
```

Because this service is reliant on an external service, it can sometimes fail; however we would like it to still return the information it did manage to retrieve itself.

```
{"id":"foo","warning":"bar service is down, oh no!"}
```

Obviously in the first scenario 200 return code is appropriate, but is it still appropriate when it "partially" fails?

As a consumer, I think I would prefer to just read the status code and then display a warning to the users or whatever; so 200 isn't very helpful to me here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The correct response code for a transient server side failure depending on external factors is `503 Service Unavailable`. [From the specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a
>   temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is
>   that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some
>   delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a
>   Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD
>   handle the response as it would for a 500 response.

Considering it a partial failure is a violation of the transactional nature of HTTP as a whole - a request either fails, or it doesn't. If you can't succesfully complete the **entire** request because of a server-side issue, a 5xx answer is according to the spec the only appropriate response.

I'm not sure how your webservice works, but if the case is really that you're contacting multiple upstream data providers, and it is not per se harmful to the client to get a partial response, you should provision it in your own protocol that it lists the elements that were correctly retrieved, and which are cached or could not be provided. In that case your response is actually a valid answer to the request, and it should be passed with `200 OK`. This scenario is comparable to having a Twitter feed on a website - if Twitter is down you can still give a meaningful answer containing a "Twitter feed currently unavailable message" along with all your other content. A meaningful answer would then still be sent with `200 OK` of course.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but being able to return some useful information will be useful for the consumer, it will allow users to still use the site in a limited fashion; which is better than not at all. One could argue I could still return the data and do a 503, but it implies the actual service is down; which doesnt feel semantically correct.

Comment: No in that case the last paragraph I added applies - in that case you send a valid answer, which by all means should be transmitted with `200 OK`. That the successfully transmitted response contains some error messages is irrelevant to the HTTP layer of the response. `503` explicitly means *"I cannot give a meaningful response right now, but I may be later"*.

Comment: Hmm, maybe. When I consume the code as a client though, I would want to implement something like circuit-breaking the calls to the service; I would expect 503 to mean something like "Dont hit me for 5 minutes, I'm having problems". With my scenario if I return a 503, I now need to check both the code *and* the response, which is more.. annoying :) I guess my point is, it would be nice if there was an appropriate HTTP code I could use instead of having to parse the response in order to work out what's happened.

Comment: There is no appropriate HTTP code because what you're describing is your protocol's responsibility. It's not like Ethernet contains error codes for non-existing HTML pages - it's just not relevant at its OSI level. If you can send a meaningful response, it's `200` as far as HTTP is concerned - the innards live on their own layer in your own protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the the same status code in both scenarios would not be a good practice. You need to validate if the external service is up and running. In other words you can just consider that as an exceptional scenario. If the external service is not up and running you can trigger that scenario through exceptions. There you will be able to catch up the status code which is returned from that external service. If it's appropriate to your solution you can send that status code or else you can set-up a custom status code and send it back to clients.

Comment: But if i just return the status code of the external service (i.e 503) that will imply that *my* service is also temporarily unavailable, which is not true; it can still return some information

Comment: You should probably be using 404 - Not Found range.

Comment: When it comes to REST API development you cannot consider if the underline services are not running and only your service is running is a good condition. You can probably give a custom error code which should be 1000+ range (eg: 1025) likewise

Comment: @MCF a response in the `4xx` range is wrong by definition - it implies a clientside error that **will not return another result upon reissuing the request**. If the server cannot fulfill a request, but may be able to in 10 seconds, it's a server error, thus `5xx` range. A `404` is actually considered cacheable by all browsers and proxies, which would break the service.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I agree with you. But one way would be using 404 as a HTTP Status code and explain the correct scenario with a custom error code in 1000 range (eg: 1025). Both client side and server side should have an agreement like this before hand. So that both the parties aware of the correct scenario.

Comment: I edited my comment to add the important line about 404 cacheability. That's why you shouldn't use it for transient conditions, even if client and server agree a proxying middle man could break it.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes agree with you. Even we can use 500 -  Internal Server Error as well since its a fault from the server end.